# Create a template using another template

Tags: angularjs, ember.js

I'm trying to create a template which renders a form and then cache that form as template so that I can use it in displaying form with user inputs while in edit.

So far I tried merging both the data (form configuration data+ form input given by user) and render the form. But this won't allow me to cache the form as template and need additional work to retrieve the user input while saving.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the best thing you can do is create *one* template that renders a form dynamically based on the form-config options.  Different config *options* can be saved and retrieved from a server as model data.  Use them to render a form.  The actual user input should be defined and saved as a separate model class.  Bottom line is that you cant really get ember to create actual new "templates" for you

Comment: @Grapho Yes correct Template part is ok, my question is when user opens the record for edit how to hook that separate model(user data) in the template created by the template model.